# Do nonconstructive proofs of isomorphism exist?

Tags: logic, reference-request, group-isomorphism, proof-theory, graph-isomorphism

I'm interested in proofs of claims of the form "Finite objects $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic" which are nonconstructive, in the sense that the proof doesn't exhibit the actual isomorphism at hand.

A stronger (and more precisely specified) requirement would be a case in which it's computationally easy to write a proof, but computationally hard to extract the isomorphism given the proof, e.g. a class of graphs for which one can easily generate triples $(G,H,P)$ with $P$ a proof that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic but for which there's no (known) efficient algorithm to take in $(G,H,P)$ and return a permutation of the vertices exhibiting the isomorphism.

Some examples of things that would fit the bill, were they to exist:

- (give a nonconstructive proof that) all objects of type $X$ are uniquely specified by their values on five specific measurements; observe that $A$ and $B$ align on all such measurements.
- The easy-to-compute function of graphs $f(G,H)$ turns out to be equal to the product, over all relabelings of $G$, of the number of edges in the symmetric differences between the edge sets of $H$ and the relabeled copy of $G$. (This occurs because of some cute algebraic cancellation or something, like how one can compute determinants in time $O(n^3)$.) Now we observe that $f(G,H) = 0$ via direct computation, and conclude that a relabeling with no difference at all to $H$ must exist.
- Groups $G$ and $H$ of order $n$, specified by their multiplication tables, can be easily shown to embed as subgroups of a larger group $K$, which we can classify and more easily prove things about. But the existence of two non-isomorphic subgroups of order $n$ in $K$ would imply something about its Sylow subgroups that we know to be false.

Are there good examples of this phenomenon? Reasons to think it doesn't happen? I would also be interested in any pointers to literature on related topics here.

Comment: Do the objects have to be finite? I missed that part when I was writing my answer.

Comment: I feel like there should be some good examples using the [probabilistic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method), or maybe some of its classic results can be rephrased as giving the existence of an isomorphism.

Comment: Or what about knot invariants?  For instance, the Jones polynomial is a complete invariant on prime knots up to 9 crossings.  So if you take two such knots, compute their Jones polynomials, and find they are the same, then there must be an isomorphism between them, i.e. a sequence of Reidemeister moves, but no obvious way to find those moves.  However, the proof is presumably by taking a pre-existing list of knots up to isomorphism, computing all their Jones polynomials, and seeing they are all distinct.  So maybe that's cheating.

Comment: (And knots are fundamentally finite objects; there are [well-known ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_theory#Tabulating_knots) to represent an arbitrary knot diagram by a finite sequence of integers or the like.)

Comment: Too boring to put as a "real" answer: The Classification of Finite Simple Groups says that every finite simple group is isomorphic to [blah blah blah], but does not provide an explicit construction for this isomorphism. So if you can construct a simple finite group of order n, and then prove that it *isn't* isomorphic to (say) $C_n$ or any of the other families except for one specific family, then you can narrow that down to a single group, but you still would not have an explicit construction.

Comment: @Kevin: I agree the *statement* doesn't give me a construction, but it's not actually clear to me that going through the proof of CFSG wouldn't give a pretty explicit description of how, if my chosen group had such-and-such properties, I could find relevant generators.

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect: That strikes me as a "too powerful" result (i.e. if you can do that, then I think you can probably find arbitrary generators for arbitrary simple finite groups), but I don't know enough group theory to properly analyze or explore that idea any further.

Comment: I really like this thread.  It has become a biglist and so a good reference for us for later studying.

Comment: Apply any classification theorem e.g. finite abelian groups, manifolds with certain properties, uniqueness of theta functions of certain weight, Uniqueness of vertex operators satisfying some relations, etc

Answer (score 47):

The simplest example I know: the existence of primitive roots tells us that if $p$ is a prime then the group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ of units $\bmod p$ is cyclic, hence isomorphic to $C_{p-1}$. However, exhibiting such an isomorphism amounts to finding such a primitive root, and the proof does not do this, nor does it really supply an efficient algorithm to do it.

I don't know what the time complexity of finding a primitive root is. The "obvious" probabilistic algorithm is to factor $p - 1$, then pick a random $a \in (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and test whether it's a primitive root by computing $a^{\frac{p-1}{q}} \bmod p$ for all prime divisors $q$ of $p-1$. This should be pretty fast in practice although it will take at least as long as factoring $p - 1$ and I don't know what the deterministic time complexity is.

Comment: You can find a prime $p$ and a primitive root modulo $p$ in probabilistic polynomial time.  For example, pick a prime $p$ such that $(p-1)/2$ is prime (you can generate a random such prime by generating random primes and applying a primality test to $(p-1)/2$), then use the randomized algorithm in your answer.

Comment: This would have been my example also. Depending on exactly when the OP accepts an isomorphism to have been exhibited, we may end up having to solve the related discrete logarithm problem.

Comment: @D.W. one thing that is missing from your comment is that the theorem Qiaochu is discussing applies to *all* primes, and finding an explicit primitive root mod $p$ for arbitrary primes $p$ (not just prime $p$ where $(p-1)/2$ is prime) is a hard task at present.  Victor Shoup wrote on p. 340 of his book on computational number theory and algebra that "there is no known way to efficiently recognize a primitive root 
modulo $p$ without knowing the prime factorization of $p − 1$."

Comment: @KCd, No, I didn't miss that.  The question asked for (efficiently constructible) examples of groups that are non-constructively isomorphic, and I'm saying that you can obtain such examples by looking at the class of groups $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times,C_{p-1}$ where $p$ is prime and $(p-1)/2$ is prime.  That provides a perfectly valid answer to the original question, and one that meets all of the conditions in the question.  There is no requirement in the question that we have to include all $p$.  You might just as well complain that this only works when $p$ is prime.

Comment: @D.W. okay, I see what you mean.  (There are nonprime m where $(\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z)^\times$ is cyclic, such as odd prime powers.)

Answer (score 25):

Here's a charmingly ugly example. Suppose $X$,$Y$, and $Z$ are simply-connected CW-complexes. Suppose each has the same homology groups as the others:

$H_0(X; \mathbb{Z}) \cong H_0(Y; \mathbb{Z}) \cong H_0(Z; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$

$H_3(X; \mathbb{Z}) \cong H_3(Y; \mathbb{Z}) \cong H_3(Z; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$

$H_5(X; \mathbb{Z}) \cong H_5(Y; \mathbb{Z}) \cong H_5(Z; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$

$H_n(X; \mathbb{Z}) \cong H_n(Y; \mathbb{Z}) \cong H_n(Z; \mathbb{Z}) \cong 0$ for all $n\neq 0,3,5$.

Then at least two of the spaces $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are homotopy-equivalent to one another. How do you know that? It's because the assumptions imply that the homotopy types of each of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ have minimal CW-decompositions with:

a single basepoint 0-cell,

a single 3-cell, so each of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ have 3-skeleton $S^3$,

and a single 5-cell, so the homotopy type is determined by the homotopy class of the attaching map of the 5-cell to the 3-skeleton.

But the boundary of a 5-cell is $S^4$. So the possible homotopy types of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are the homotopy classes of maps $S^4 \rightarrow S^3$, i.e., the fourth homotopy group of the three-sphere, $\pi_4(S^3)$.

A quick calculation yields that $\pi_4(S^3) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. So there's only two homotopy-types of spaces of the kind that $X,Y$, and $Z$ are assumed to be. So at least two of the three have to be homotopy-equivalent to one another. But it's non-constructive: the information given isn't enough to pin down which two are homotopy-equivalent. So you get non-constructive isomorphism in the homotopy category of topological spaces.

It's more non-constructive than that, though. Even if you use an argument like this to figure out that $X$ and $Y$ have to be homotopy-equivalent to one another, that's a long way from having continuous maps between them, an explicit homotopy equivalence.

Answer (score 22):

We know that any two finite fields with the same cardinality are isomorphic.  On the other hand, suppose you have two different polynomials $f, g \in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$ which are irreducible and have the same degree.  I'm not aware of any easy computation which would give an explicit isomorphism of fields $\mathbb{F}_q[x] / \langle f \rangle \simeq \mathbb{F}_q[x] / \langle g \rangle$, which would amount to finding a root of $g$ in the first field.

Answer (score 18):

If a purely set theoretic example is acceptable:

[The Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) says that a bijection between two sets $A$ and $B$ exists when there are injections $i : A \rightarrow B$ and $j : B \rightarrow A$.

This [theorem is not constructively valid](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123482/is-there-a-constructive-proof-of-cantor-bernstein-schroeder-theorem). There is information on why this is the case in the answers at that link to a MathOverflow question. Cantor's original proof, for example, used the well-ordering theorem (which is equivalent to the axiom of choice).

[Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09193) is a recent paper which shows that Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein implies excluded middle.

Comment: If I remember correctly, we can explicitly write down this bijection! I’m confused in what sense this is not constructive

Comment: Oh I see, because the law of excluded middle must be used. However, I feel that such tenets of classical logic are implicit in the original question - most contexts in which isomorphisms arise are contexts in which “normal” logic applies, such as the law of the excluded middle. Otherwise, (a proof of) CSB is explicit - so, in common language, constructive - in providing such a bijection

Comment: (please correct me if I’m wrong, I’m not a set theorist, just a student who once had to write down the explicit bijection as an exercise!)

Comment: @FShrike Hmm, I'm not sure I see what you mean by the tenets of classical logic being implicit in the question. Classical logic *itself* is non-constructive: LEM, in its general form, is non-constructive. In fact, you can obtain a system of intuitionistic (constructive) logic from classical logic by just removing LEM. There's some discussion of LEM's non-constructivity in the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522011/must-non-constructive-existential-proofs-use-axioms-of-foundation-or-choice)

Comment: Also, you say *"Otherwise, (a proof of) CSB is explicit - so, in common language, constructive - in providing such a bijection"*. Within a constructive system, you cannot (in general) have a proof for the CSB theorem because you cannot have a general purpose "algorithm" for constructing these bijections given only the two injective functions.

Comment: To me, a constructive proof (in the sense of common language, not formal logic) is one which explicitly gives an algorithm, or expression, for all key processes / indeterminates that feature in the proof. A constructive isomorphism would be a map which is described in great detail, such as avoiding the use of (unknowable) choice functions. A non-constructive isomorphism would be one that we know exists (in ZFC), that we can indirectly show *must* exist, but we struggle to find explicit expressions for any / all of the key processes. The “wild” automorphisms of $\Bbb C$ come to mind.

Comment: (cont.) so I feel that, in a context where LEM is common - proof by contradiction featured often in my algebra textbook(s)! - I think, maybe, it is the wrong tone of “constructive” that is being talked about here. That was all. I’m not OP! Just voicing a concern / confusion

Comment: @FShrike You might be right, I'm also not an expert, but I've never heard of anyone calling a proof "constructive" which, out of necessity, uses LEM. I would be surprised to see that. The thing is that LEM itself, in general, can introduce uncomputability. Consider [Markov's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_principle). It is a consequence of LEM but it's not valid intuitionistically. Also, regarding textbooks: in my experience, most algebra textbooks are ok with doing non-constructive proofs (this isn't *bad*, just an observation regarding something you said).

Comment: From the wikipedia article, here's an example of something that is equivalent to Markov's principle (which, again, just follows from LEM) that shows something exists without any way to construct it: "For each real number x, if it is contradictory that x is equal to 0, then there exists y ∈ R such that xy = 1." Note that there are [uncomputable real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant#Uncomputability).

Comment: The 'explicit' bijection in the CSB proof does not (in general) yield an algorithm. The description involves cases on propositions that may not be algorithmically decidable. For instance, the mathoverflow answer by Todd Trimble about injections between ℕ and a subset of ℕ involving non-halting Turing machines. In that case, the described function would involve cases on whether or not machines halt, which is a well known undecidable problem. This is why excluded middle is a problem for logic _internal to_ computation. It corresponds to the assertion that every proposition is decidable.

Comment: Let $V$ be any nonempty set. If $\vartheta:\mathcal{P}(V)\to\mathcal{P}(V)$ is (inclusion) order-preserving, then it has a fixed point *explicitly* given by: $$S:=\bigcup_{R\in\mathcal{P}:R\subseteq\theta(R)}R$$Now if $f:A\to B,g:B\to A$ are given injections between nonempty sets, we can return a bijection by: (i) explicitly finding a fixed point $S$ for the order-preserving map $\mathcal{P}(A)\to\mathcal{P}(A)$,$X\mapsto g(B\setminus f(A\setminus X))$ and (ii) declaring: $$h:A\to B,\,x\mapsto\begin{cases}g^{-1}(x)&x\in S\\f(x)&x\notin S\end{cases}$$Every step was constructive, explicit.

Comment: The proof is not valid in *constructivist logic*, perhaps, but is still .. constructive, in the sense I see it commonly used. I’m confused

Comment: @FShrike The way I understand it is that $x\in X$ or $x\not\in X$ is constructively invalid.

Comment: @FShrike Deciding membership in an arbitrary set is not computable (I think you run into issues here). I sort of see what you're saying, but if you consider such things "constructive," the definition of that word seems like it depends on arbitrary "syntactic" choices (compared to defining it in terms of computability etc). For example, consider a nonconstructive statement "… then z is the smallest natural satisfying P" can be rewritten as "then z = $\mu x(P(x))$" with the unbounded $\mu$ operator. Is this now constructive because we are "constructing" it with $\mu$? Note P could be undecidable

Answer (score 13):

Lovasz ["A note on the Line Reconstruction Problem", J Combinatorial Theory B, 13, 1972] proved that two finite simple graphs $G,H$ on $n$ vertices with the same collection of unlabeled proper subgraphs must be isomorphic if each has $m > \frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{2}$ edges. It is an attack on the well known edge-reconstruction conjecture. The proof uses inclusion-exclusion to count the set of monomorphisms $G\to H$, and shows that $|G\to H| = |H\to H|$, but $|H\to H|$ is of course greater than zero.

By inclusion-exclusion $|G\to H| = \sum_{X\subseteq G} (-1)^{|E(X)|}|X\to \overline{H}|$ where $X$ runs over all graphs with $V(X)=V(G)$ and $E(X)\subseteq E(G)$, and $\overline{H}$ is the complement of $H$. Similarly, $|H\to H| = \sum_{X\subseteq H} (-1)^{|E(X)|}|X\to \overline{H}|$. Since $G$ and $H$ have the same unlabeled proper subgraphs, the terms on the right hand side with $|E(X)| < m$ must be identical in both equations, and since $m > \frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{2}$, the terms with $|E(X)| = m$ must be zero. Hence, $|G\to H| = |H\to H|$ and so there is at least one isomorphism from $G$ to $H$.

I have never seen a way the proof can be modified to find an explicit isomorphism from $G$ to $H$ using known isomorphisms from $G-e$ to $H-\phi(e)$, where $e\in E(G)$ and $\phi :E(G)\to E(H)$ is some bijection.

Answer (score 11):

A contrived example to link this to the law of excluded middle is to start with some proposition $p$ and then consider the set $\{0 \mid p\} \cup \{1 \mid \neg p\}$. It's immediate that classically, this set is isomorphic to $\{2\}$. However, actually having the isomorphism entails knowing whether $p$ is true or false.

Answer (score 5):

A particular example:

$\mathbb{P}$ : Set of all primes

$\mathbb{N}$ : Set of all positive interger.

$\mathbb{P}\subset \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ is an infinite set $[$ a list of [proofs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem)$]$

Any infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has the cardinality $|\mathbb{N}|=\aleph_0$.

Hence there is a bijection between $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{N}$.

But it's difficult to construct such bijection.

Comment: Why is it difficult to construct such a bijection? Map each prime to the number of primes below it.

Comment: Sure but what’s non constructive about it?

Comment: I think the point is not what theorems are needed, but that computing the bijection appears to be computationally hard.  I'm not aware of any efficient (polynomial-time) algorithm to compute this function in either direction.

Comment: @D.W. Computationally hard and non-constructive are not synonymous.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku, I am well aware of that.  In this specific question, the original poster writes that they are looking for "a case in which it's computationally easy to write a proof, but computationally hard to extract the isomorphism given the proof".  That is why it is relevant that it appears to be computationally hard to compute this bijection.

Comment: I thought at first that this answer missed the point.  But D.W.'s comment has convinced me that it is actually an excellent answer: quite straightforward, and it points the way toward many similar sorts of answers.

Answer (score 2):

There are non-constructive techniques for Graph Isomorphism, such as Weisfeiler--Leman (WL). While it is known that WL cannot place Graph Isomorphism into $\textsf{P}$, it serves as a complete invariant for a number of graph families including planar graphs, graphs of bounded tree width, graphs of bounded rank width, and graphs of bounded genus.

To use WL as an isomorphism test, we run WL on the disjoint union of our two input graphs $G, H$. If the multiset of colors for $G$ differ from that of $H$, then we know that $G$ and $H$ are non-isomorphic. For the above families of graphs, this is enough to decide isomorphism.

While the multiset of colors on its own does not in general yield an isomorphism, it is possible to use WL to compute a canonical labeling. Grohe & Neuen have a write-up of this in the appendix here (https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.10330).